# Machine learning with continuous training/model update (tensorflow or something else)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am wondering if there are projects/examples with any machine learning library (tensorflow, etc) which can do continous training kind of simulate an animal or pet.

What do I mean by animal/pet?
Let's assume I have these hardware robot.

Inputs:

1. Touch sensor, which returns number from 0 to 255 depends on touching force.
2. Microphone.
3. Webcam.

Outputs:

1. Moving module, which can move forward/backward and left/right. Let's say just some simple wheels system with 4 input pins. If I send +5v (binary 1) in pin 1, it goes forward, to pin 2, it goes backward, to pin 3, left, pin 4, right.
2. Speakers.

Everything is connected to central Computer (raspberry Pi or if not enough CPU/Memory then Microsoft Surface Pro with 4 cores i7 3+GHz CPU and 32 GB RAM).

Idea is to connect hardware inputs mentioned above to input of neural network, outputs to output of neural network and put this conditions:
Minimize bad feelings and maximize good.

If touch sensor returns number more than 128, it is bad feelings (pain}, if touch sensor returns less than 127 it is good feelings (pet). If battery is less than 20% it is bad feelings. Loud noise from microphone is bad feelings. In programming terms 3 variables to minimize and one to maximize.

When I connect it all together and switch it on, I will train it like a baby. Show some pictures, tell something, pet it for good work, etc. Show where is the battery (maybe I will put wireless charger, that it can do it by itself). I understand, that it will take long time, maybe years.

My problem now, that most of the examples which I found so far works like train first and then use this already trained neural network. Or use pre-trained by others neural network. I could not find an example with continuous training and usage of neural network.

Questions:

- Is it possible to implement this with current machine learning technologies/libraries (tensorflow, etc)? Let's consider first only software part, if I have unlimited hardware.
- If it is not possible, then why?
- If it is possible, then links to examples or general approach description will be very helpful.
- If it is possible, then what hardware will be needed?

P.S. of course I do not expect it to be as smart as human, even not as a dog/cat. Maybe like fly or mosquito :)
Also I would like to get high level answer without going very deep into details like, how would you implement moving module, etc. And everything as simple as possible.

Comment: This is a very broad question. I suggest looking at Reinforcement Learning. Richard Sutton's book is available for free online. Tensorflow provides tf agents.

Comment: @dgumo I understand that it is broad question, but I do not need exact answer. I am asking for direction or generic answer if it is possible at all. Your comment is very good. Thanks a lot .

Comment: what u want sounds like DQN or DDQN